# Convexity of conditional expectation

Tags: distributions, density-function, conditional-expectation, convex

Define $g(k)\equiv\mathbb{E}(X|_{X>k})$ and assume that the probability density $f$ of  $X$ is twice continuously differentiable. Is there a sufficient condition in terms of $f$ that imply that $g^{\prime \prime}(k)>0$?

EDIT: I tried to first restrict attention to log-concave densities and then find a subset in that class.

$g^{\prime \prime}(k)>0$ if and only if

$$ -f(k)\bar{F}^2(k)+f^{\prime}(k)\bar{F}(k)\int_{k}^{+\infty}\bar{F}(k)\mathrm{d}k +2f^2(k)\int_{k}^{+\infty}\bar{F}(k)\mathrm{d}k\\
=f(k)\Bigl(f(k)\int_{k}^{+\infty}\bar{F}(k)\mathrm{d}k-\bar{F}^2(k)\Bigr)+
\int_{k}^{+\infty}\bar{F}(k)\mathrm{d}k\Bigl(
f^{\prime}(k)\bar{F}(k)+f^2(k)\Bigr)
>0$$

However, if $f$ is log-concave, then $
f^{\prime}(k)\bar{F}(k)+f^2(k)>0$ while $f(k)\int_{k}^{+\infty}\bar{F}(k)\mathrm{d}k-\bar{F}^2(k)<0$ (see [Bagnoli and Bergstrom (2005)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00199-004-0514-4)); I could proceed no further